# Sequential execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, interview-questions, queue

I made a class that I think satisfies the conditions:

1. `Action`s can be added to the queue at any time by any number of clients.
2. `Action`'s executing in the order in which were added.
3. Only one `Action` executing at time.

```
public sealed class SequentialTaskScheduler
{
    private static volatile SequentialTaskScheduler instance = null;

    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    SequentialTaskScheduler()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ThreadProc);
    }

    public static SequentialTaskScheduler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new SequentialTaskScheduler();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void AddToQueueForExecution(Action action)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(action);
    }

    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Action item;
            bool isSuccessfull = false;
            isSuccessfull = queue.TryDequeue(out item);
            if (isSuccessfull)
            {
                item();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for the advice about dangers of such an implementation. And also will be grateful for the advice how to improve it.

**Update:**

I get feedback on this task from company.

- uncertain use of volatile
- use threadsafe singleton or singleton
- Task.Factory.StartNew take pool from thread but does not return it.
- use busy loop with Thread.Sleep is not elegant solution.

How to improve code with those remark's? I think that first two reason are non constructive, but the third and four are constructive. i will be grateful for the advices.

Comment: Required reading: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: You are aware of BlockingCollection? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @paparazzo, it was test task. With 3 condtions. Implementation could be whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have few suggestions, and modified the code.

1. Use Lazy singleton pattern instead of Double check singleton, avoid usage of volatile

   ```
   private static readonly Lazy<SequentialTaskExecutor> _lazy = new 
   Lazy<SequentialTaskExecutor>(() => new SequentialTaskExecutor());
   ```
2. Tasks should be cancelled and disposed properly. Since the task we want to run for long time, create a new task using Task.Factory.StartNew with Cancellation tokens and TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

   ```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ExecuteTask, _token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
   ```
3. Class should implement IDisposable interface, so created threads can be cancelled properly and items in the queue are cleared

   ```
   public class SequentialTaskExecutor : IDisposable

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!disposedValue)
           {
               if (disposing)
               {
                   // clear the items in queue.
                   Action item;
                   while (_queue.Count != 0)
                   {
                       if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                       {
                       }
                   }

                   _tokenSource.Cancel();
                   _executionTask.Wait();
                   _tokenSource.Dispose();
                   _executionTask.Dispose();
               }

               disposedValue = true;
           }
       }
       catch
       {
       }
       finally
       {
           _tokenSource = null;
           _executionTask = null;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use Smart waiting instead of Busy waiting in tasks.

   ```
   private void ExecuteTask()
   {
       bool isTaskCompleted = true;
       while (true)
       {
           Action item;
           if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
           {
               while (_queue.Count != 0)
               {
                   if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                   {
                   }
               }

               break;
           }

           if (isTaskCompleted)
           {
               isTaskCompleted = false;
               var innerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               {
                   if(_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                   {
                       return;
                   }
                   if(_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                   {
                       item();
                   }

               }, _token).ContinueWith((ants) =>
               {
                   if(ants.IsCanceled || ants.IsFaulted)
                   {
                       isTaskCompleted = true;
                   }
                   else if(ants.IsCompleted)
                   {
                       isTaskCompleted = true;
                   }
                   _currentInterval = _minimumInterval;
                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  " Task execution complted _currentInterval : " + _currentInterval);
               });
           }
           else
           {
               // Raise the interval till maximum value
               if (_currentInterval < _maximumInterval)
               {
                   _currentInterval++;
               }

               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  " Task waiting complted _currentInterval : " + _currentInterval);
               Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_currentInterval));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Complete source code is as follows

   ```
   public class SequentialTaskExecutor : IDisposable
   {
       private static readonly Lazy<SequentialTaskExecutor> _lazy = new Lazy<SequentialTaskExecutor>(() => new SequentialTaskExecutor());
       private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _queue = null;
       private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = null;
       private CancellationToken _token;
       private int _maximumInterval = 10;
       private int _minimumInterval = 1;
       private int _currentInterval = 0;
       private bool disposedValue = false;
       Task _executionTask = null;

       private SequentialTaskExecutor()
       {
           _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
           _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
           _token = _tokenSource.Token;
           _executionTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ExecuteTask, _token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
       }

       public static SequentialTaskExecutor Instance
       {
           get
           {
              return _lazy.Value;
           }
       }

       public void AddToQueueForExecution(Action action)
       {
           _queue.Enqueue(action);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task added " + _queue.Count);
       }

       private void ExecuteTask()
       {
           bool isTaskCompleted = true;
           while (true)
           {
               Action item;
               if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   while (_queue.Count != 0)
                   {
                       if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                       {
                       }
                   }

                   break;
               }

               if (isTaskCompleted)
               {
                   isTaskCompleted = false;
                   var innerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                   {
                       if(_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                       {
                           return;
                       }
                       if(_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                       {
                           item();
                       }

                   }, _token).ContinueWith((ants) =>
                   {
                       if(ants.IsCanceled || ants.IsFaulted)
                       {
                           isTaskCompleted = true;
                       }
                       else if(ants.IsCompleted)
                       {
                           isTaskCompleted = true;
                       }
                       _currentInterval = _minimumInterval;
                       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  " Task execution complted _currentInterval : " + _currentInterval);
                   });
               }
               else
               {
                   // Raise the interval till maximum value
                   if (_currentInterval < _maximumInterval)
                   {
                       _currentInterval++;
                   } 

                   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Task.CurrentId + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  " Task waiting complted _currentInterval : " + _currentInterval);
                   Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_currentInterval));
               }
           }
       }

       protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
           try
           {
               if (!disposedValue)
               {
                   if (disposing)
                   {
                       // clear the items in queue.
                       Action item;
                       while (_queue.Count != 0)
                       {
                           if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
                           {
                           }
                       }

                       _tokenSource.Cancel();
                       _executionTask.Wait();
                       _tokenSource.Dispose();
                       _executionTask.Dispose();
                   }

                   disposedValue = true;
               }
           }
           catch
           {
           }
           finally
           {
               _queue = null;
               _tokenSource = null;
               _executionTask = null;
           }
       }

       public void Dispose()
       {
           Dispose(true);
       }
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with **vishnu vardhan**'s answer. However I disagree with his 4th suggestion, which I think is hardly an improvement.

It still uses `Thread.Sleep` which should never be used in production code: you shouldn't pay your worker to sleep. Either use a `BlockingCollection` or write your own synchronization using `ManualResetEvent`. If no tasks are being processes your thread should just hang on some wait handle. It should not spin in a loop, constantly consuming CPU resources, while doing no meaningful work.

I also think it might be a good idea to refactor your code into an actual [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx).

P.S. [Common pitfall, when using Task.Factory.](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)